# Como usar paginação em asp:datalist?

Tags: asp.net, asp

Olá, encontrei alguns códigos em vários sites, só que não encontrei um método de fazer paginação no asp:datalist . Eu gostaria que tivesse os números em baixo, opção de ultima pagina, primeira pagina. Segue o print da tela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]